# Formula for coefficient of a certain polynomial to the nth power

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, multinomial-coefficients

I have a polynomial that looks like

$$p_{3,10}(x_0, x_1, ... x_9) = (x_0 x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 + x_0 x_1 x_2 x_3 x_5 + ... + x_5 x_6 x_7 x_8 x_9)^3$$

How do I determine the formula for the coefficient of each term in the expanded polynomial? Note that inside the parentheses, we are summing a total number of ${10}\choose{5}$ $x_{i}$'s.

In general, I would like a formula for the coefficient of each term of the more general polynomial

$$p_{r,t}(x_0, x_1, ... x_t) = (x_0 ... x_{t/2 - 1} + x_0 ... x_{t/2 - 2} x_{t/2} + ... +  x_{t/2} ... x_{t - 1})^r$$

I have tried brute force algebraic manipulation. I have also tried using combinatorial arguments, but I can't quite make it work. I am now trying to find a recurrence relation in terms of $r$ for a fixed $t$, and I will try to find a recurrence relation in of $t$ for a fixed $r$ as well. If you have any other ideas I would be grateful!

*Note: I forgot to mention the following two constraints: $r \in \mathbb{N}$, and $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2 \vert t$.*

**Update**

It was pointed out to me that this problem is equivalent to counting how many ways a certain $15$-element multiset can decompose into $3$ $5$-element sets. I am researching how to express this counting formula explicitly.

**Second update**

I found [this paper](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/1496018/1/1511.06142v1.pdf) which seems to offer a way of counting the sets as described in my previous update. Please let me know if anyone has advice on how to adapt the formula on page 6 to my current problem.

Comment: The coefficient of a monomial in your first example is the number of ways the 15-element multiset that corresponds to the monomial can be decomposed as the union of three 5-element sets. It's a purely combinatorial problem.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That makes sense, thanks for the help. How would I go about finding an explicit formula for the number of ways a specific "$3 \cdot 5$"-element set could be formed using this idea?

Comment: This is the number of partitions of the number $15$ (the degree of each monomial) into $10$ nonnegative parts (the degrees of $x_i$). This is the same as the number of partitions of $15$ into parts of size at most $10$.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907406/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-integer-partitioning-with-restricted-number) for a fairly effective way to compute such numbers. I doubt you will find an explicit formula, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: [This Sage cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1j00LwjAMhu-F_oeAl0Zkn36cvHqfepNNxsigsK6SVtF_b2thN0MOz-FJ3sRDqCOUhRScsJbCE5tAt2oD9a_LDQQuErewgjM9mBzN3oF63wvsKlhHKrGrE1UL1diVibaLt8OuSLRfvEPwpJCCQvTlYwx51sPpOQ9e29mppsGMJjIhtOePQinMf9HY2RrdT1GL32TOsldML2IX91_5SXGDInXzkOdQteEIRswGS-OoBx1iVJzEL58tUJ0=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) computes the answer to your question.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks. I wonder if there is a way to work backwards from the coefficients generated by this code to find an explicit formula for the coefficients (searching through different expressions based on factorials/chooses).

Comment: In all likelihood, no such formula exists.